# Loading SQLite assets from CDN with COOP & COEP headers

Tags: sqlite, webassembly

I have a web site which loads the JS, Images & CSS assets from CDN servers. Now I am planning to implement SQLite WASM module to have a client side Database. The SQLite WASM module uses SharedArrayBuffer to implement the DB. In order to load the SQLite related assets, I need to load it through Web Worker and have to set COOP and COEP headers for the document. Only then the OPFS persistence layer will work.

My question here is, already I am loading my JS, CSS & Images from another CDN server which is in a different domain. Now if I want to implement SQLite DB, I need to set the COOP and COEP headers for the document. If I set the headers for the document, then other assets JS, CSS & Images are not loading from CDN servers.

How to load the SQLite related Web Worker and other SQLite WASM related files by setting COOP and COEP headers only for these files and load other JS, Images & CSS files from CDN.

Or only when I set my document cross origin isolated using COOP & COEP headers and when self.crossOriginIsolated = true is returned in the console, the SQLite WASM module will work by persisting the DB using OPFS?